# Appexchange - change version for public listing

Tags: appexchange

Just passed security review for our app and published to appexchange.  Now want to change version for new package to fix some bugs.  There is a warning that the new version won't be available with Get It Now button without security review.  Our next scheduled security review is one year.  I thought you could provide new versions in the interim.  What do I have to do to list a new version now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1**

When in the AppExchange publishing console you should be able to see a list of your recently uploaded pacakges, which will include the version you last uploaded.

Along side the listing should be a link to start security review—you need to click that and go through the screens answering the questions that come up. This is a self-assessment process and you **do *not* have to pay anything**.

[image: Start review link in the AppExchange publishing console]

**Step 2**

Once you've done that you need to edit your listing and switch to the "Offering" tab. There, under the list of packages is a link saying "Change Packages":

[image: Change packages link location]

That will bring up a multi-select picklist allowing you to specify which versions of the package are available for listing out of all those that have been through the security review (paid or self assessment). Ensure the package version you ran through security in step one is in the **selected** list.

[image: Available package selection]

**Step 3**

Select the version of the application that should be linked to the listing. This is done in using the drop down shown in the first screen shot of step 2, where it says "Select the latest version of your application".

**Step 4**

Profit.

Comment: Thanks for that answer - I did not know you had to do that to use Get it Now...

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  There should be some documentation on this, but it is missing from the manual provided by Salesforce.